# Image will not display in contentview

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, xamarin, android-imageview

In `Xamarin`, I have a simple `Activity` that loads up with a five second wait before another `Activity` is loaded.

The first `Activity` has an image as part of the `Layout`, yet this image is not being displayed.

Here is my `Activity` code:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.SplashActivity);

    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    var testActivity = new Intent (this, typeof(TestStartup));
    StartActivity (testActivity);
}
```

Here is my `SplashActivity` layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/Splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/SplashImage"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The application waits five seconds, and then the TestStartup `Activity` loads, however, the image is not displayed during the five second wait. How can I display this image while the `Activity` waits five seconds?

Can I please have some help with this code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not shown because you are blocking the UI Thread with

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

You should get rid of this kind of logic. Relying on `x secs` it is always wrong. The computation you are waiting for could be ready before, making the remaining waiting period a wast, or could require more the `x secs`. To `"fix"` your issue you can use `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, 5000)`, and put the logic you need to be executed inside the `run` method. This way, at least, the UI Thread will not be blocked

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Xamarin's tutorial for creating splash screens in Android:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/

It looks like you were on the right track, but they use a theme rather than setting the content view.  As previously mentioned, your layout isn't being displayed because your sleep method is blocking the UI Thread.  Using a theme is a good way to get around this, and you can reuse a lot of what you already have.